# Spring Boot 2.6.4 - Embedded Derby Database not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, derby

I have a simple "HelloWorld" like Spring Boot MVC Project. I tried to use a simple embedded Derby DB to store my Data. Very simple nothing special. In my Pom i imported

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
    <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

And added @Entity and @Id to my Model (see below).

Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/")
public class BeerController {

    @Autowired
    BeerService beerService;

    @GetMapping(path = "/beer")
    public String getSomeBeers() {
        return "Beer was here";
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/addbeer")
    public void addBeer(){
       beerService.setNewBeer(1,"HeadyTopper", "GoodAsFuck", 5.6, 4.9);
    }
}
```

Model

```
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor
@Getter @Setter
@Entity
public class Beer {

    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String desc;
    private double abv;
    private double rating;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Beer{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", desc='" + desc + '\'' +
                ", abv=" + abv +
                ", rating=" + rating +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Service

```
@Service
public class BeerService {

    @Autowired
    BeerRepository beerRepository;

    public void setNewBeer(int id, String name, String desc, double abv, double rating) {
        Beer beer = new Beer(id, name, desc, abv, rating);
        //beerRepository.save(beer);
        System.out.println(beerRepository.findAll());
    }
}
```

When i now start the Spring Boot App i get following Errors

```
2022-03-03 18:18:26.732  WARN 9064 --- [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "drop table beer" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "drop table beer" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlString(SchemaDropperImpl.java:387) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaDropperImpl.java:371) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropFromMetadata(SchemaDropperImpl.java:246) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.performDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:156) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:153) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:81) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:335) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1498) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at com.example.basics.BasicsApplication.main(BasicsApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Schema 'SA' does not exist
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.handleException(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.execute(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.execute(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException: Schema 'SA' does not exist
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.getSchemaDescriptor(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.sql.StatementUtil.getSchemaDescriptor(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.QueryTreeNode.getSchemaDescriptor(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.QueryTreeNode.getSchemaDescriptor(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.DDLStatementNode.justGetDescriptor(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.DDLStatementNode.getTableDescriptor(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.DDLStatementNode.getTableDescriptor(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.DropTableNode.bindStatement(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepMinion(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepare(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.conn.GenericLanguageConnectionContext.prepareInternalStatement(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    ... 39 common frames omitted

2022-03-03 18:18:26.740  WARN 9064 --- [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "create table beer (id integer not null, abv double not null, desc varchar(255), name varchar(255), rating double not null, primary key (id))" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table beer (id integer not null, abv double not null, desc varchar(255), name varchar(255), rating double not null, primary key (id))" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:458) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:442) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.createFromMetadata(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:325) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.performCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:169) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:124) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:164) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:81) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:335) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1498) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at com.example.basics.BasicsApplication.main(BasicsApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "desc" at line 1, column 62.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.handleException(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.execute(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.execute(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException: Syntax error: Encountered "desc" at line 1, column 62.
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.ParserImpl.parseStatementOrSearchCondition(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.ParserImpl.parseStatement(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepMinion(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepare(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.conn.GenericLanguageConnectionContext.prepareInternalStatement(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.14.2.0.jar:na]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
```

Above it i also get some strange

```
    2022-03-03 18:18:26.109  WARN 9064 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource  : Registered driver with driverClassName=org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver was not found, trying direct instantiation.
2022-03-03 18:18:26.334  INFO 9064 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Driver does not support get/set network timeout for connections. (Feature not implemented: No details.)
```

I tried all kind of `application.properties` edits like setting up the Dialect manually or change the `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=` to `create-drop` or `update`

The Error message doesnt change at all. What am i missing? Is Derby not working anymore with Spring Boot 2.6.4?

Answer (score 0):

Old Entity Class:

```
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor
@Getter @Setter
@Entity
public class Beer {

    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String desc; <<--- USING DESC AS A ATTRIBUTE NAME
    private double abv;
    private double rating;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Beer{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", desc='" + desc + '\'' +
                ", abv=" + abv +
                ", rating=" + rating +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Fixed:

```
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor
@Getter @Setter
@Entity
public class Beer {

    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String descr;
    private double abv;
    private double rating;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Beer{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", desc='" + descr + '\'' +
                ", abv=" + abv +
                ", rating=" + rating +
                '}';
    }
}
```

I Simply had to rename the one Attribute to not match the SQL Statement `descending` and now it works. So if you have the same issue just search for any Attribute Names that could have a Name same as a SQL Statement